# Eclipse groovy project doesn't recognize groovy-only jar

Tags: eclipse, groovy, gradle

We have a groovy project that uses a library of groovy code packaged as a jar. The code is not compiled, but is still in groovy form (these are classes, not scripts), as in:

```
com/foo/bar/X.groovy
com/foo/bar/Y.groovy
etc.
```

We use this in a gradle project and the project builds and runs with no problem.

However, eclipse (Kepler with groovy plugin) refuses to recognize the groovy classes from this jar file. The jar file is in the build path (handled by "gradle eclipse") and I can see it in eclipse and even open it and see the groovy.

But our client code that's trying to use the jar file shows errors in eclipse, "unable to resolve class com.foo.bar.X".

Is there some trick to getting eclipse to recognize a groovy-only jar file?

Comment: Are you saying that you are shipping a Jar with Groovy class sources, and then compile/run against it? That's uncommon, and it would be interesting to know how you make that work with Gradle. I'd be surprised if you could make it work with Eclipse.

Comment: You're correct. The jar is from an old project, and groovy is perfectly happy with such a jar. Gradle is too. It's set up as a local dependency, just like any other jar file.

Comment: Would be interesting to get the details. I can imagine that you can compile with the sources on the compile class path (like it works for `javac`). But I doubt you can run with the sources on the runtime class path, or compile/run in Eclipse.